# how to find javascript memory leaks

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks

I think I have javascript memory leak in my program. Actually it is not my software, I assigned to find the problem.
I read a lot of document to how to find a leak but I can not find it. This is the snapshot of my memory. I compare to of them and find out after a period it adds 30MB to memory. I do not know what the (array) means and how can I find out the problem.

Thank you

[image: snapshots of my memory]

Comment: You forgot the snapshot and your code

Comment: where is the snapshot?

Comment: Dear user., since you are newbe to SO.. you don't ve permission to post image.!! you need enough reputation to do that... Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour..

Comment: Sorry I can not add the snapshots, instead I inserted a link of snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try chrome developer tools or mozilla firebug for profiling. You can profile cpu/memory(heap) using google chrome developer tools.

Comment: I tried them before. if you look at my snapshots I used chrome dev tools. but I can find it.